# Resttemplate 422 Unprocessable Entity Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I have a post service with collection on Postman. I can successfully get a response with Postman. This service is a bit complicated with its body and headers. I want to call this service from SpringBoot using Resttemplate. But I am getting the error mentioned in the title. I'm probably making a mistake somewhere in the request list or sending the wrong data type, but I have no idea and I've been trying for a long time. I hope you can help me.
First of all,
**I will share the raw body that I post request with Postman:**

```
    {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "customer_country": "NL",
    "customer_language": "en",
    "partner_metadata": {
        "sales_channel": "inPath",
        "device":"app"
    },
    "request": [
        {
            "policy_type": "comprehensive_travel_insurance",
            "policy_type_version": "7",
            "is_return": false,
            "policy_start_date": "2022-06-07T10:22:30.925568+01:00",
            "policy_end_date": "2022-06-13T20:55:00+02:00",
            "departure_country": "LT",
            "destination_country": "EE",
            "total_tickets_price": 78.99,
            "number_of_adults": 1,
            "number_of_children": 0,
            "number_of_infants": 0,
            "trip_start_date": "2022-06-13T19:45:00+02:00",
            "trip_end_date": "2022-06-13T20:55:00+02:00",
            "flights": [
                {
                    "legs": [
                        {
                            "departure_datetime": "2022-06-13T19:45:00+02:00",
                            "arrival_datetime": "2022-06-13T20:55:00+02:00",
                            "flight_number": "BT905",
                            "marketing_airline_iata_code": "BT",
                            "operating_airline_iata_code": "BT",
                            "departure_airport": "VNO",
                            "arrival_airport": "TLL",
                            "departure_country": "LT",
                            "arrival_country": "EE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "departure_datetime": "2022-06-13T19:45:00+02:00",
                    "arrival_datetime": "2022-06-13T20:55:00+02:00",
                    "departure_country": "LT",
                    "arrival_country": "EE",
                    "departure_city": "VNO",
                    "arrival_city": "TLL"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Headers on Postman:**

[image: Headers]

**Example endpoint where I call the service:**

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/abc")
public ResponseEntity<String> postQuotes(){
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("X-Api-Key", "****");
    headers.add("Date", "Thu, 02 Jun 2022 22:16:39 GMT");
    String signatureKeyID = "Signature keyId=\"****\",";
    String algoritm = "algorithm=\"hmac-sha1\",";
    String signature = "signature=\"***"";
    String authHeader = signatureKeyID.concat(algoritm).concat(signature);
    headers.add("Authorization", authHeader);
    HttpEntity<QuoteRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<>(fillQuoteRequest(), headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> postForEntity = rest.postForEntity(quoteURL, entity, String.class);
    return postForEntity;
}
```

**Methods where I set Entity objects:**

```
    private Legs fillLegs(){
    Legs legs = new Legs();
    legs.setDepartureDatetime("2022-06-13T19:45:00+02:00");
    legs.setArrivalDatetime("2022-06-13T20:55:00+02:00");
    legs.setFlightNumber("BT905");
    legs.setOperatingAirlineIataCode("BT905");
    legs.setMarketingAirlineIataCode("BT905");
    legs.setDepartureAirport("VNO");
    legs.setArrivalAirport("TLL");
    legs.setArrivalCountry("LT");
    legs.setDepartureCountry("EE");
    return legs;
}

private Flights fillFlights(){
    Flights flights = new Flights();
    List<Legs> legsList = new ArrayList<>();
    legsList.add(fillLegs());
    flights.setLegs(legsList);
    flights.setDepartureDateTime("2022-06-13T19:45:00+02:00");
    flights.setArrivalDateTime("2022-06-13T19:45:00+02:00");
    flights.setDepartureCountry("LT");
    flights.setArrivalCountry("EE");
    flights.setDepartureCity("VNO");
    flights.setArrivalCity("TLL");
    return flights;
}

private QRequest fillQrequest(){
    QRequest qRequest = new QRequest();
    List<Flights> flightsList = new ArrayList<>();
    flightsList.add(fillFlights());
    qRequest.setFlights(flightsList);
    qRequest.setPolicyType("comprehensive_travel_insurance");
    qRequest.setPolicyTypeVersion("7");
    qRequest.setIsReturn(false);
    qRequest.setPolicyStartDate("2022-06-07T10:22:30.925568+01:00");
    qRequest.setPolicyEndDate("2022-06-13T20:55:00+02:00");
    qRequest.setDepartureCountry("LT");
    qRequest.setDestinationCountry("EE");
    qRequest.setTotalTicketsPrice(78.99f);
    qRequest.setNumberOfAdults(1);
    qRequest.setNumberOfChildren(0);
    qRequest.setNumberOfInfants(0);
    qRequest.setTripStartDate("2022-06-13T19:45:00+02:00");
    qRequest.setTripEndDate("2022-06-13T20:55:00+02:00");
    return qRequest;
}

private PartnerMetadata fillPartnerMeta(){
    PartnerMetadata pm = new PartnerMetadata();
    pm.setDevice("app");
    pm.setSalesChannel("inPath");
    return pm;
}

private QuoteRequest fillQuoteRequest(){
    QuoteRequest qr = new QuoteRequest();
    qr.setRequest(fillQrequest());
    qr.setPartnerMetadata(fillPartnerMeta());
    qr.setCurrency("EUR");
    qr.setCustomerCountry("NL");
    qr.setCustomerLanguage("en");
    return qr;
}
```

**As a result of all, the error returned when I call the service:**

[image: Error Message]

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnprocessableEntity: 422 Unprocessable Entity: "{"type":"validation_error","message":"An API error occurred.","errors":{"request":["Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."]}}"
```

Can you help me find the source of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see `flights` and `legs` are supposed to be sent as list, but you are sending them as objects.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I realized. The error was due to the fact that I did not send the request as a list. request, flights and legs should all be lists